# Solving $\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{1} \left (( \ln u)^{-z} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac {(\ln u)^{k-z}}{u \cdot k!} \right ) \mathrm {d}u$ with $z>0$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, summation, gamma-function

$$\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{1} \left (( \ln u)^{-z} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac {(\ln u)^{k-z}}{u \cdot k!}  \right ) \mathrm {d}u$$

**My attempt :**

Distributing the integration over the two parts as follows:

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} ( \ln u)^{-z} \mathrm {d}u - \int_{0}^{1} \left ( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac {(\ln u)^{k-z}}{u \cdot k!}  \right ) \mathrm {d}u.$$

Solving for first part : let $ \ \displaystyle \ln u = -y$

Then $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} ( \ln u)^{-z} \mathrm {d}u = (-1)^z \int_{0}^{\infty} ( y)^{-z} e^{-y} \mathrm {d}y = (-1)^z \Gamma (-z+1) .$

Solving for Second part :

Let

$\displaystyle f(u) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac {(\ln u)^{k-z}}{u \cdot k!}  $

Then $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} f(u) \mathrm {d}u = F(1) - F(0),$
where $\displaystyle F'(u) = f(u) $

Using same substitution,

$ \ \displaystyle F(u) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac {1}{k!} \int \frac {(\ln u)^{k-z}}{u} \mathrm {d}u \implies  F(y) = - (-1)^z \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac {(-1)^k(y)^{k+1-z}}{k!(k+1-z)} \\ \{ \ y \ ; \  0 < y < \infty \}$

Now $\displaystyle  I = (-1)^z \Gamma (-z+1) + F(y)|_{0}^{\infty} $

OR

$$\displaystyle I = (-1)^z \left ( \Gamma (-z+1) + \lim _{y\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac {(-1)^k(y)^{k+1-z}}{k!(k+1-z)} - \lim _{y\rightarrow 0} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac {(-1)^k(y)^{k+1-z}}{k!(k+1-z)} \right )$$

The summation $\displaystyle  \ \ \lim _{y\rightarrow 0} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac {(-1)^k(y)^{k+1-z}}{k!(k+1-z)} $ can be finite if $ 0 < z < 1 $ or I may be wrong.

---

**My Doubt :** What I did is correct or not and is a there a closed form for this integral ?

---

Thank you for reading.

Comment: As the resulting integral I get $\gamma -\sin (\pi  n) \Gamma (1-z) \csc (\pi  (n-z))$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler's constant and $\Gamma$ denotes the Euler Gamma function and $\csc(x)$ gives the cosecant of $x$.

Comment: @EldarSultanow Please tell what was your go on this ?

Comment: I obtained it computationally using `Integrate[Log[u]^(-1)-Sum[(Log[u]^(k-z))/(u*k!),{k,0,n-1}],{u,0,1}]`. If you wish I can try to extract the intermediate steps.

Comment: @EldarSultanow  Ok, I get it but I want some rigorous work here. Alteast I know that there exist a closed form for the integral. Thank you for the efforts.

Comment: Just one observation that hopefully can simplify things: when I split up both integral parts $\int_{0}^{1}( \ln u)^{-z}\mathrm {d}u - \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac {(\ln u)^{k-z}}{u \cdot k!}  \mathrm {d}u$, I can treat them separately and obtain: $\int_{0}^{1}( \ln u)^{-z}\mathrm {d}u-\frac{\pi  \Gamma (1-z) \csc (\pi  (n-z))}{\Gamma (1-n) \Gamma (n)}=\gamma -\sin (\pi  n) \Gamma (1-z) \csc (\pi  (n-z))$.

Comment: @Eldar Sultanow  Yes, It is helpful. I figured it out and am trying to prove it rigorously.. will take some time.

Comment: I have accepted this answer you submitted on Quora.